# Zend Framework loading views without re-loading the layout template

Tags: php, javascript, json, model-view-controller, zend-framework

I need to load a profile layout and then have all of the profile views load into that layout without re-loading the layout, so that I can cache a big json object in the clients browser, to allow for data to be available on subsequent views, without having to do a new HTTP request for every view in my profile controller.

Is it possible to load the layout template and then load views into it, by disabling their layout template, so that the layout template never re-loads, only the view within?

Another option would be to have an iframe inside of a layout and then load the views into the iframe, by disabling their layouts, so that just the view is rendered.

Just need to know if this is possible and what the best option would be.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Cannot you just use another action?

Comment: So do you want to load HTML via AJAX and put it inside your layout? Or what is it that you want exactly? It's quite unclear.

Comment: Well let me help. I need to cache a large JSON object in one page that has an iframe on it. All other pages need access to this data, so I need to load them into an iframe and never refresh the main page, once logged in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the views where you do not want a layout try:

```
$this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
```

This should prevent the layout from being shown.

If, for some reason, you want the same action from the same controller called many times but load the layout once (must be a better way to organise yourself) but you could always try:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    static $firstTime = true;
    if($firstTime){
        $firstTime = false;
    } else {
        $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout(); //disable layout
    }
}
```

I'll try to give a better example:
Lets say you have a controller foo with 3 views: index, contact, news.

```
class Foo_Controller extends Zend_Controller
{
     //...

     public function indexAction()
     {
        //normal view layout loads
     }
     public function contactAction()
     {
        //normal view layout loads
     }
     public function newsAction()
     {
        //no layout for this
        $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout(); //disable layout
     }
}
```

So the views that need a layout have one. The ones that do not do not. Unless you are saying layout but really thinking of something else then Zend_View_Helpers_Layout you will have t post some code to help us help you!

Comment: But can I load say the index view for a controller into a layout with an iframe and then load all other views in that controller into the iframe? I need it to where the layout page is only loaded once for my profile controller, so that I can cache profile data once and use it across all profile views.

Comment: I am not sure what it is you are asking exactly.

Comment: basically I have a need to cache a json object in the profile controllers layout page and not reload it everytime I load a view from the profiles controller, that way the data is cached in the clients browser and available when viewing the other views for that controller. Make Sense?